# EF4 VS2010 not mapping linked tables properly

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I have a pretty standard linked table setup

Table1
Id - PK, seeded

Table2 
Id - PK, seeded

Table3
Table1Id - FK
Table2Id - FK

For some reason, when using the designer to create the edmx in VS2010, table 1 exists already.  When adding Table2 and Table3, they get added, but no relationship gets attached between Table3 and Table1.  As well, the designer usually does not include the linking table which is what I would like to continue to do as well.  Anyone know why this would be occuring?  The existing edmx is quite large and I'd prefer not to delete everything and re-add!